# Como retornar dados em formato JSON de uma WebAPI .net

Tags: c#, json, .net, api

Estou fazendo uma chamada dentro da API para que me retorne dados de consumidor, porém gostaria de saber como retornar esses dados pro cliente em formato JSON.

Meu controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]   
public async Task<ActionResult> GetConsumidor()
{
  ConsumidorDAO consumidor = new ConsumidorDAO();
  string dadosConsumidor = consumidor.getDados();

  return (dadosConsumidor);
}
```

Eu faço uma consulta no banco de dados para trazer alguns dados de um consumidor como nome, sobrenome, etc.

```
public string getDados()
{
  OracleCommand lOracleCommand = lOracleConnection.CreateCommand();
  String query;
  string nome = "";

  try
  {
    query = "select nome " +
      "from crd.cliente " +
      "where cpf_cgc = 'xxxxxxx'" +
      "  and empresa_origem = '367' ";

    lOracleCommand.CommandText = query;
    OracleDataReader reader = lOracleCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      nome = reader["nome"].ToString();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception lException)
  {
    _status += lException.Message + "\n";
    lOracleCommand.Connection.Close();
  }

  return nome;
}
```

Comment: O cliente seria o que exatamente? por exemplo, você iria salvar os dados em um arquivo de texto?

Comment: Eu so retorno os dados em formado JSON com as informaçoes

Answer (score 0):

*JSON* é uma representação de objeto no formato Javascript (*Javascript Object Notation*). 
Como você está retornando somente uma string, isso não se encaixa como um objeto, objetos são formados por zero ou mais duplas de chave e valor.

Se você insiste em retornar um *JSON*, pode fazer um objeto com uma propriedade que tem seu valor como string e serializa-lo no retorno da *API*, segue um exemplo.

Exemplo:

```
//outros using
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


public class ResultadoObjeto
{
    public string Propriedade { get; set; }
}

[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]   
public async Task<string> GetConsumidor()
{
   ConsumidorDAO consumidor = new ConsumidorDAO();
   string dadosConsumidor = consumidor.getDados();

   //aqui gero e preencho o objeto
   var resultadoObjeto = new ResultadoObjeto();
   resultadoObjeto.Propriedade = dadosConsumidor;

   //aqui o transformo em JSON e retorno
   string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(resultadoObjeto);
   return (json);

}
```

Comment: Fiz como no exemplo porém na hora do retorno não é possível de converter  string em System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult @Paz

Comment: modifique o ActionResult para string, editei a resposta para o código que funcionará corretamente